# Trouble accessing child objects in Firebase

Tags: list, object, firebase

I'm trying to pull a list of connected users in Firebase to simply populate a select dropdown. My problem is that I can't seem to access the child objects properly.

Using connectedUsers.userName (see below code) works but only for my own user data, it doesn't pull anything else.

It seemed to me like changing "myUserRef.on" to "userListRef.on" and using something like "snapshot.child('userName').val()" should work but it just throws undefined. The same goes for "connectedUsers.child.userName", I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

In the below code by changing to "userListRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot)" I can successfully add and remove user data from Firebase, and log all of the objects to the console and all data looks fine when I drill down the objects. I just need a way to access that data so I can put all connected users into a select dropdown or remove them from it when they disconnect.

```
var userListRef = new Firebase('https://myaccount.firebaseIO.com/users/');
var myUserRef = userListRef.push();

// ADD USER DATA TO FIREBASE
var userId = $('#myIdInput').val();
var userName = $('#nameInput').val();
myUserRef.push({userId: userId, userName: userName});

// READ USER OBJECTS AND FIRE ADDUSER FUNCTION
myUserRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
var connectedUsers = snapshot.val();
console.log(addUser);
//addUser(connectedUsers.userId, connectedUsers.userName);
});

// ADD USER TO SELECT DROPDOWN
function addUser(userId, userName) {
var modSelect = $('#tsmmodsendto');
modSelect.append($('<option></option>').attr("value", userId).text(userName));
}

// READ USER OBJECTS AND FIRE REMOVEUSER FUNCTION
myUserRef.on('child_removed', function(snapshot) {
var connectedUsers = snapshot.val();
console.log(removeUser);
//removeUser(connectedUsers.userId, connectedUsers.userName);
});

// REMOVE USER TO SELECT DROPDOWN
function removeUser(userId, userName) {
var modSelect = $('#tsmmodsendto');
modSelect.append($('<option></option>').removeAttr("value", userId).text(userName));
}

// ON DISCONNECT REMOVE USER DATA FROM FIREBASE
myUserRef.onDisconnect().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written won't work properly because each user is writing to:

/users/PUSH_ID/PUSH_ID

And is then listening at:

/users/PUSH_ID

So every client is going to be listening only to its own data and will never see anyone else's data. In order to view other people's data, you need to all be listening / writing to the same path.

In your question you mention you see "undefined" if you change to listening at /users. Could you simplify your code, and use that approach, and perhaps then I can provide a more helpful answer?

Or if I'm not understanding correctly, please simplify and clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did try not pushing each user to it's own id but the problem I ran into then is that once someone leaves it removes ALL of the data for everyone on disconnect instead of just removing their own. I thought that by doing it this way I could somehow still gather up the child data by using "userListRef.on" instead of using "myUserRef.on" as this would listen to the parent and not the child. What seems odd to me is the lack of ability to still gather child data when listening to the parent in this way.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. If you onDisconnect().remove() on a reference only for a user's own data, it won't remove all of the data for all users.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, without pushing to myUserRef using userListRef.onDisconnect().remove(); removes ALL data, is there an argument I need to pass to make it only remove that user's data that I'm missing?

Comment: Never mind, I got it.
What was throwing me was the forEach function in Firebase, it seemed to me that it would do a normal for loop but it doesn't seem to work that way. I did a normal for loop over the keys and got it to work fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that a normal for() loop will traverse the keys in a browser-defined order, not in Firebase order (so if you set priorities on your data, the JS for() loop won't reflect that)

Comment: Ah I never thought about that, I don't have priorities set in this case but will keep that in mind going forward.